# Google Login Hitting Twice?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-client, google-authentication

I'm using Google Login via JS and it appears my code is getting data twice.  I'm not sure why this is occurring.

When I click my "Log In with Google" button, it spits out (console.log(result)) data for the user.  THEN a prompt occurs asking me to choose an account of mine (I'm logged into several google accounts).  When I click the account I'd like, the code then spits out that user data again.

Why is this occurring? It's a problem because where I spit out the data, I'd like to make a ajax call to verify the user and then redirect them.  So in essence, it's trying to do this twice -- which is not cool, what if I don't want to login using the credentials google passes back on the first go around?

```
(function() {
   var po = document.createElement('script');
   po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
   po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
   var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
 })();

function googleLogin() {
    var additionalParams = {
        'callback': googleCallback
    };

    gapi.auth.signIn(additionalParams);
}

function googleCallback(authResult) {
    if (authResult['status']['signed_in']) {
        gapi.client.load('oauth2', 'v2', function() {
            gapi.client.oauth2.userinfo.get().execute(function(resp) {
                console.log(resp);
            })
        });
    } else {
        console.log('Sign-in state: ' + authResult['error']);
    }
}
```

**Update:** If I sign out of all my Google accounts (with the exception of one and only one), the call to google is still duplicated.  This time it logs in and I see console.log() outputting data twice.  Access tokens are identical.

**Update 2:** console.log(resp) is outputting twice

**Update 3:** Just more clarification:

[image: firebug]

Comment: What do you see being outputted twice? "console.log(resp);" or "console.log('Sign-in state: ' + authResult['error']);"; I assume it's the later?

Comment: console.log(resp); the user's info twice.  In my original post, its the default user first.  And then the user info of the acct they select. In my update, its the default twice.

Comment: When I followed the tutorial here https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/javascript-flow but used your code within "gapi.client.load", "console.log(resp);" is only called once.

Comment: So bizarre.  and when you tried, were you already logged into several Google accounts?

Comment: I take it back. "console.log(resp);" is called twice, and it is indeed Bizarre. I get it when I run the example page for the first time. I get the double call when it pops up the small rectangular "welcome back" banner. The second time I press the button it logs once. I've posted an answer which might be of help.

Comment: Yep, you're right. It is being called twice, even if I replace the call to "gapi.client.load" with a simple console log (hence why I deleted my answer). Very odd indeed. It only occurs when the rectangular "welcome back" appears, after this the console.log is only called once.

Comment: Thanks for checking this out.  Can't for the life of me wrap my head around it.

Comment: No problems. I'm as baffled as you. I too want to find out the problem. I'll get back to you if I find out. At least your not alone in your findings!

Comment: Found the answer! See my un-deleted answer.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You are encountering two calls to "console.log(resp);" within your "googleCallback" function because:

> The function that you define for your sign-in callback will be called
>   every time that the user's signed in status changes

This quote is taken from the ["Monitoring the user's session state"](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/session-state) webpage.

As you can see in the article, the  authorization result object has three different status "method" values:

- null
- PROMPT
- AUTO

So your callback code is being triggered when the login prompt appears ("PROMPT") and when the "Welcome back" banner appears ("AUTO").

To stop your callback code from dealing with each trigger event you could change your code as follows:

```
function signinCallback(authResult) {
    if (authResult['status']['signed_in']) {
        // Update the app to reflect a signed in user
        // Hide the sign-in button now that the user is authorized, for example:
        // document.getElementById('signinButton').setAttribute('style', 'display: none');

        if (authResult['status']['method'] == 'PROMPT') {
            console.log(authResult['status']['method']);

            gapi.client.load('oauth2', 'v2', function () {
                gapi.client.oauth2.userinfo.get().execute(function (resp) {
                    console.log(resp);
                })
            });
        }
    } else {
        // Update the app to reflect a signed out user
        // Possible error values:
        //   "user_signed_out" - User is signed-out
        //   "access_denied" - User denied access to your app
        //   "immediate_failed" - Could not automatically log-in the user
        console.log('Sign-in state: ' + authResult['error']);
    }
}
```

This code will only call the "gapi.client.oauth2.userinfo.get()" function if a user is signed-in and the event which triggered the callback is of type "PROMPT".

Comment: And you're seeing '1' only once in console?  [Mine is still displaying it twice](http://imgur.com/l5QxdME).

Comment: Will this work if i only have 1 account? Will the "PROMT" type event fire in that case?

Comment: @Kicsi I'm pretty sure it will

Comment: Great answer. Saved me a bunch of time!

Answer (score 0):

Google always go through status 'PROMPT', but through status 'AUTO' just when the user has a previous success login and he could be automatically log in.