# Google+ Sign-in callback firing multiple times and requires multiple clicks for login

Tags: javascript, callback, google-plus

I've implemented a G+ login into an upcoming web-app and have several issues with the login procedure. When clicking the Sign-in button, the callback is fired, the user is logged in, but then after a second or two, the callback is fired again (3-4 times in a row!) and the user is logged right back out. Yet, if I click the Sign-in button multiple times, quickly, the user remains logged in, after 2-3 attempts.

On top of that, when signing out, the callback seems to get fired twice as well for no apparent reason at all.

I am logging both the return values of login and logout (authResult) and there is absolutely no difference what so ever in their values (no different status method or anything).

I have tried using different login methods (HTML button, JS button render) but to no avail (same issues).

The website in question is: [composer.syntax-design.at](http://composer.syntax-design.at)

Comment: Signing in worked OK for me just now. Is it possible you have 3rd party cookies disabled in your browser or similar restrictions?

Comment: I've just checked (using Chrome), all cookies are allowed. You could log in right away without needing to click multiple times? Maybe I should add that signing in the first time works without problems, just the sign-ins afterwards, when the app already has permission, is skrewed up - sorry, forgot to mention that

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Login Hitting Twice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23020733/google-login-hitting-twice)